# Function valid in test mode only

Tags: solidity, testing

Let's say we have a SmartContract that require a huge amount of iterations to reach a certain state, when something interesting happens. Creating a test for proving the contract behave correctly will require a lot of time and a lot of simulated addresses. So an idea could be having that threshold to a smaller value just in test environment: I think a function callable just in test to lower that threshold value, that cannot be called in production, because otherwise could be interpreted as a potential fraud  method. Is this possible? Any alternatives?

Comment: You have the truebit protocol for off-chain computations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to have the number of iterations passed to the contract during deployment (as a parameter in the constructor), and deploy the contract twice, being one the real contract (deployed on the mainnet), and the other (with lower number of needed iterations) the test/verifiable contract (deployed on the ropsten network).

Since both contracts would have the same bytecode, they would be comparable even using etherscan, and one could run the verification code on the contract deployed on the ropsten network for free, and then use the real contract in the mainnet with total confidence.

Comment: Seems a reasonable solution, or, at east the only option I received till now :)